# Change html with an animation effect in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

I am having a shiny app with some ui elements.
Is there a way to replace some HTML (e.g. div / div content) with an animation effect, similar to what shinyjs::show(anim=T) does?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  
  actionButton("change","change"),
  tags$div(id="someDiv",
           "test"),
  
  hidden(tags$div(id="withAnim", "Displayed with animation"))
  
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  observeEvent(input$change, {
    shinyjs::html("someDiv", "changed without animation")
    shinyjs::delay(1000, show("withAnim", anim=T, animType="fade"))
  })
 
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `shinyjs::html` doesn't provide this utility. We can write our own js code and use `shinyjs::runjs` to run it when button is clicked.

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  
  actionButton("change","change"),
  tags$div(id="someDiv",
           "test"),
  
  hidden(tags$div(id="withAnim", "Displayed with animation"))
  
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  observeEvent(input$change, {
    shinyjs::runjs("$('#someDiv').fadeOut(500, function(){$(this).text('changed without animation').fadeIn();})")
    shinyjs::delay(1000, show("withAnim", anim=T, animType="fade"))
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]